# Unity Entities not rendering in play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I have tried to Instantiate an entity using code:

```
blobAssetStore = new BlobAssetStore();
GameObjectConversionSettings settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(defaultWorld,blobAssetStore);
Entity entity = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(gameObjectPrefab, settings);      
entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new Translation { Value = position });
```

I have tried using the ConvertToEntity script. I have also created a subscene, all three methods are not rendering. I can see the entities in the Entity Debugger all the entities have a Translation, and the relevant render components, everything looks good. These are the ECS packages I have installed:

- Burst 1.3.3
- Collections 0.9.0-preview.6
- Entities 0.11.1-preview.4
- Hybrid renderer 0.5.2-preview.4
- Jobs 0.2.10-preview.12

Using Unity 2020.1.0b12.3931

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome

Comment: Is what you are converting a prefab as the name suggests or a game object from the hierarchy

Comment: I am converting a prefab, not in the hierarchy. I have tried to put the prefab in the hierarchy, just with the ConvertToEntity script and that too does not show. Trying to downgrade some of the packages to match with a project that does show entities now.

Comment: Is it a 2D or 3D prefab? do you need some rotation?

Comment: It is a 3D prefab. The issue was it was  not rendering at all. But I found my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems that even though this line of code creates an entity :

```
Entity entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(gameObjectPrefab, settings);
```

It does not set the LocalToWorld coordinates as below:
[image: Snip of Enity Prefab LocalToWorld]

If I call Instantiate after the above line, with the previously created entity:

```
Entity entity = entityManager.Instantiate(entityPrefab);
```

Then the LocalToWorld is set correct to the Translation position passed in:
[image]

Even if I try and set the LocalToWorld component to the correct position using this:

```
 entityManager.SetComponentData(entityPrefab, new LocalToWorld { Value = new float4x4(quaternion.identity, position) });
```

It still does not show, my only guess at the moment is that it has a Prefab component attached to it, as shown below:

[image]

Although even trying to remove this component does not show the entity created:

```
 entityManager.RemoveComponent(entityPrefab, typeof(Prefab));
```

I am doing some more research on why this is and will post any finding here.
The complete code now looks like this :

```
private void InstantiateEntity(float3 position)
{
    blobAssetStore = new BlobAssetStore();
    GameObjectConversionSettings settings = GameObjectConversionSettings.FromWorld(defaultWorld, blobAssetStore);        
    Entity entityPrefab = GameObjectConversionUtility.ConvertGameObjectHierarchy(gameObjectPrefab, settings);
    Entity entity = entityManager.Instantiate(entityPrefab);
    entityManager.SetComponentData(entity, new Translation { Value = position });        
}
```

I hope this helps someone in future.